# Longest alternating subsequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, recurrence

A sequence x1, x2, x3, ...,xn, is zig-zag if

[image: 1]

If `X = 3, 4, 8, 5, 6, 2` then the length of the longest zig-zag subsequence is `5`(corresponding to `3, 8, 5, 6, 2`, or `4, 8, 5, 6, 2`).

We define Z(i, 0) to be the EVEN length of the longest zig-zag subsequence that finishes with xi.

We define Z(i, 1) to be the ODD length of the longest zig-zag subsequence and finishes with xi.

Here's the solution recurrence:

[image: 1]

Now my question is if there's another way to build the recurrence with the variable Z having only parameter `i` and incorporating `0 and 1` inside the function.
If we define `Z[i]` to be the length of the longest zig-zag subsequence(odd or even) that finishes with xi, in what way can we express the information if z[i] is odd or even ?
What would that recurrence be ?

EDIT: I worked a little bit on the recurrence and I came up with this solution. I think it is correct. Can someone else confirm ?
Let's define c[i] to be the longest zigzag subsequence (odd or even) of the prefix Xi that finishes with xi.
If we have only one element in the sequence then c[1] = 1
To calculate c[i] for i > 1, first we calculate the longest zigzag subsequences for (i-1) elements (both odd and even). We choose the maximum of the two and add 1. We use `c[j] mod 2 == 0` controls to select only even lengths.

[2 http://imageshack.com/a/img537/402/egyXmk.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/402/egyXmk.jpg)

Comment: somehow isn't the index 'j' itself tells you the parity (odd/even) for state c[j]? Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Whether the length of the subsequence is even or odd is an important part of information without which the formula won't work. And it can't be derived from `i`.

Comment: That might not be true. I'm editing my post and posting a solution with one parameter which i think is correct.